# Is there a way to add a comma to a float in iOS, or at least display it as a currency?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have the following:

```
NSLog(@"Total: $%.2f", paymentsToday);
```

It currently displays:

```
$16000.00
```

How do I make it display:

```
$16,000.00
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [NSNumberFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for this.

This should do the trick:

```
NSNumberFormatter *priceFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[priceFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
[priceFormatter setCurrencyCode:@"USD"];
[priceFormatter setCurrencySymbol:@"$"];
NSString *formattedOutput = [priceFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat: paymentsToday]];
NSLog(@"Total: %@", formattedOutput);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a NSNumberFormatter to set the currency format:

```
    NSNumberFormatter* formatter=[[NSNumberFormatter alloc]init];
    [formatter setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    NSLog(@"%@",[formatter stringFromNumber: @(paymentsToday)]);
```